# Trying to remember the name of a reincarnation villainess novel (trapped in a tower for years)

Tags: story-identification, novel, reincarnation

The main character is a girl who's reincarnated as a villainess in a novel she read in her past life. The character she became is a girl who commands two villainous brothers to do her bidding. The novel mentioned but didn't go into detail about how they had a terrible past where the brother relatives sent them away and their younger sister dies of a disease when their young. Little did the main character know that they all four children were locked in a tower of the main house for several years without ever being let out and that the little sister died of malnourishment. Now the main character is trying to figure out how to save the two brothers and sister from this fate and escape the tower.

Details I remember include: The mc was the daughter of the families maid, and when her mother died the family continued to take care of her. The mc was close friends with the daughter and two sons despite her being a commoner and them nobles. The children's parents die as well from an epidemic and the uncle says he's going to send them away for their safety until the epidemic stops, but the next morning all of them wake up to find they've been locked up in a small dark tower in their sleep. The uncle visits them once and tells them that they'll only be there temporally but as the months turn into years only being served one meal a day and never speaking to anyone from outside the tower again they start to loose hope. The daughter has a weak constitution and is constantly battling a fever and the oldest son is suffering from horrible depression. The second son and the main character are trying to find a way to save everyone and get revenge on the uncle.

This novel wasn't fully updated when I read it so I don't know anymore, but I'm trying to find the name so that I can try to purchase the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! "A Happy Ending for Villains"

Sasha Sanchez and her mother are peasants under hire of the Serpentine family and they lived peacefully until the great plague hit the lands. First, her mother is taken and then the plague too took the lives of the Masters of the Serpentine household.

It was during the funeral that Sasha remembered her past as an Orphan Korean girl and that she possessed the body of the Final Boss of the novel. While vowing to protect the Serpentine children who are both her Childhood Friends and are like a family to her, the group is instead pitted into political intrigue that will shape and force them to be Driven to Villainy for their revenge.

Sasha decided to let herself be evil and fight for what has been denied to her and the Serpentine children by the world, a happily ever after.

[image]